# NotFoundHttpException after changing webiste hosting, sub-domain

Tags: 8, installation

After changing webiste hosting (Drupal 8) I got this very un-intuitive error message:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: in Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront->processInbound() (line 43 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/PathProcessor/PathProcessorFront.php).

Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorManager->processInbound('/', Object) (Line: 157)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteCollectionForRequest(Object) (Line: 141)
Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\NestedMatcher\NestedMatcher->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 258)
Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\DynamicRouter->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 185)
Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ChainRouter->doMatch('/', Object) (Line: 155)
Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\ChainRouter->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 84)
Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 154)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object, 'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object) (Line: 120)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 628)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

The files are all the same, other files on ftp/website (besides Drupal) are accessible and works fine.

I've cleared cache via Admin Panel before moving anything.

I've also tried remove it manually:

```
TRUNCATE cache_config;
TRUNCATE cache_container;
TRUNCATE cache_data;
TRUNCATE cache_default;
TRUNCATE cache_discovery;
TRUNCATE cache_dynamic_page_cache;
TRUNCATE cache_entity;
TRUNCATE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE cache_render;
TRUNCATE cache_toolbar;
```

but I guess it's not the point.

The previous website was working on `http://someurl1.com/site/` (sub-domain) and new one is under `http://someurl.com/` (top domain). But even moving everthing on new hosting to `/site/` doesn't change a thing.

When I changed database connection settings in `settings.php` to something wrong intentionally I get:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user...
```

So I guess it's not the database connection problem either.

Using `http://.../core/rebuild.php` also didn't help.

Comment: Have you checked the apache logs (or what webserver you use) ? Is mod_rewrite enabled ?

Comment: This `NotFoundHttpException` error happened to me after TRUNCATEing all cache* db tables. `drush cr` was no help. It went away when copying the full database with all data.

Comment: I have the same problem with drupal 8 installations. when I add /install.php to my url i got the drupal installation page and works good to me. http://localhost/mydrupal8website/install.php

Comment: Did you check all paths and names and host patterns in settings.php?

Answer (score 0):

Check database connection through `drush sql-cli` and `show tables`, I got the same error because of an empty database once.

If the data is of no importance, you can run `drush site-install` to re-install Drupal from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this after transferring an entire database (Drupal 8.8.1) from production back to dev.

Same error on every single route I tried.

Clearing the cache alone didn't fix it, but `composer dump-autoload` (*"Generated autoload files containing 565 classes"*) followed by `drush cr` did.